# Pusher Private or Public?

Tags: javascript, php, pusher

Hi Guys i have the following codes from Pusher, I tested and it seems ok for use like for example.

**Javascript in Pusher-app.php**

```
    var pusher = new Pusher('OMITTED_MY_API_KEY', {
         cluster: 'ap1',
         encrypted: true
     });

     var channel = pusher.subscribe('**private_username-id**');
         channel.bind('my_event', function(data) {
     alert(data.message);
});
    </script>
```

**Pusher-server.php**

```
require('Pusher.php');

    $options = array(
    'cluster' => 'ap1',
    'encrypted' => true
);

    $pusher = new Pusher(
       'OMMITED_API_KEY',
       'OMMITED_API_KEY',
       'OMMITED_API_KEY',
       $options
    );

    $data['message'] = 'hello world';
    $pusher->trigger('**private_user_name-id**', 'my_event', $data);
```

**User Table**

```
  ----------------------------------------------
  | ID | username | password | notify_channel  |
  |--------------------------------------------|
  | 1  |  userA   | kjdiejdk | private_userA-1 |  
  | 2  |  userB   | kjdiejdk | private_userB-2 |  
  | 3  |  userC   | kjdiejdk | private_userC-3 |  
   ---------------------------------------------
```

**Follower Table**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| INDEX | USERID | FOLLOWERS                                               |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|   1   | userA  | s:47:"array('id' => userA, 'id'=>userC, 'id' =>userD)"; |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

For each of my wordpress users, I created a database column 'NOTIFY-CHANNEL' where in this case the channel of **private_username-id** is called for this specific user.

Channel name will be $wpdb->get_rows from the database and **echo** to the javascript so every user will have their own unique channel since the channel specify in the javascript is controlled by server side script.

**My Question**

> 1) I am building an activity stream, I realise even without the **private-** prefix (public channel), as long as server side in PHP I am careful in $pusher-trigger('**CHANNEL NAME**', '**EVENT_NAME**', $data) and ensure the user is_logged_in(), there doesn't seems to be a problem even if all my channels go public.
>
> What's the disadvantage of using a public channel, and when do I actually have to use a private channel? And in the instance above, by just adding the private- prefix and I am already easily listening to the channel, I don't see how secure it is.
>
> So before I proceed to further use pusher for the activity stream and notification of my site, any past users can enlighten me how I should better do this?

```
'
```

> 2) I would like to have other users "follow" other users, so when User A and User B follows User C, User A and User B will receive a notification whenever User C adds a blog. So if User A follows 1000 users do I mean I need to create 1000 different channels?
>
> I have the table above, if i have something from userA i want to send to his followers, i get the followers from the table above, unserialise and send to each of them.
>
> So how do I create a new channel for each "following"? I'm stuck here and I don't understand the algorithm to better implement this.

```
  '
```

> 3) In the case of the javascript codes above, I do not wish to put it as inline Javascript code and wish to put it in a separated pusher-client.js. May I know how do I echo the CHANNEL_NAME to the pusher-client.js dynamically or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

> What's the disadvantage of using a public channel, and when do I
>   actually have to use a private channel? And in the instance above, by
>   just adding the private- prefix and I am already easily listening to
>   the channel, I don't see how secure it is.

The disadvantage of using public channel is that, anyone could able to subscrible to a channel, and listen event fires on that channel. Think of a private message service, if user A is chatting with user B in channel C, and user X subscribes to channel C, X can view all messages between A and B.

The private channel has an authentication mechanism, so by implement logic code on authenticate method, it can reject unauthorized subscriptions.

> So how do I create a new channel for each "following"? I'm stuck here
>   and I don't understand the algorithm to better implement this.

A is followed by F1, F2, F3
Channel names should be: following-A
Then when A publishes a blog, F1, F2, F3 can be notified.